# latexmk preview command is not working with skim

Tags: errors

I recently installed MacTex on mac version 11.7.4. I am using Skim as my file previewer and I've configured it in a %HOME%/.latexmkrcedit file. When I use latexmk -pv, it gives me this output:

> Rc files read:   NONE Latexmk: This is Latexmk, John Collins, 7 Jan.
> 2023. Version 4.79. No specific requests made, so using default for latexmk.  Latexmk: Nothing to do for 'template.tex'.  Latexmk: All
> targets () are up-to-date
> ------------  Running 'NONE  "template.dvi"'
> ------------  Latexmk: Program not implemented for this version.  Command line:     'NONE  "template.dvi"'  Collected error summary (may
> duplicate other messages):    view: Command for 'view' gave return
> code 1
>
> Latexmk: If appropriate, the -f option can be used to get latexmk to
> try to force complete processing.

And when I run latexmk -pvc, I get the output "Latexmk: I could not run previewer."

I don't know why this is happening, any ideas?